# NumPy gradient over multidimensional irregularly spaced array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to use the `np.gradient` for a multidimensional irregularly spaced array. I've got a naive solution working, but it requires a `for` loop which will be a bottleneck for real computations.

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.geomspace(2*np.pi, 8*np.pi, 500)[None,:]
y = np.geomspace(2*np.pi, 8*np.pi, 500)[:,None]

XX, YY = np.meshgrid(x,y)

f      =  np.sin(x) * np.cos(y)
dfdx   =  np.cos(x) * np.cos(y)


grad = np.zeros_like(f)
for row in range(f.shape[0]):
    grad[row] = np.gradient(f[row], XX[row], edge_order=2)

print(np.linalg.norm(grad-dfdx, ord=2))
```

Is there a way to do this computation using `np.apply_along_axis`? The reason for needing this because `np.gradient` does not accept multidimensional arrays for the distance argument, they must either be scalars or a 1-D array.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is not a performance tool.

Comment: All rows of `XX` are the same, so `np.gradient(f,XX[0], axis=1, edge_order=2)` is the same as `grad`.

Comment: I guess this was a poor test data-set. That's not the case for the real dateset I'm trying to mimic. I will try and come up with a more representative example.

Comment: I was thinking you might do something like `np.diff(f,axis=1)/np.diff(XX,axis=1)`; that is use `diff` to get the differences in both `f` and `XX`.  But it looks like `gradient` uses a 3 point calculation, with `a*f[2:]+b*f[1:-1]+c*f[:-2]`, with the coefficients derived from the `x`.  I imagine it can be generalized to allow for different `a,b,c` for each row, but it could take a lot of work.  Anyways, if you really understand how the gradient works, you could calculate this from scratch without any loss of speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.geomspace(2*np.pi, 8*np.pi, 500)[None,:]
y = np.geomspace(2*np.pi, 8*np.pi, 500)[:,None]

XX, YY = np.meshgrid(x,y)

f      =  np.sin(x) * np.cos(y)
dfdx   =  np.cos(x) * np.cos(y)

    
grad = np.array(
    [np.gradient(f[row], XX[row], edge_order=2) for row in range(f.shape[0])]
)

print(np.linalg.norm(grad-dfdx, ord=2))
```

which returns `0.08971829701854393`.